# How do I measure server power consumption by user?

Tags: server, power-management

Is there a command, package, or hardware that can be used to calculate how much power each user on my server is drawing?

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu by default can measure power usage by user. For that matter, unless the serer has some way of reporting it, like iDRAC, without power-monitoring hardware, I don't think it is possible. In theory, you could take the total power consumption and use some math to figure out how much each users uses. At least for the total power, you could use a [Kill-a-watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_A_Watt) device.

Comment: Not possible because that would mean that you would have to measure the power consumption per application or service. And even more, to calculate a user's share of applications that are used by multiple users. This is simply not possible and not something that any OS can actually measure with any kind of real accuracy